# Como obtener el nombre de la clase y metodo en el catch error?

Tags: java

Buenos dias estoy haciendo un logger generico en java para obtener nombre de la clase y metodo, pero quiero obtenerlo del catch, ya tengo un clase generica donde imprimo la excepcion, quiero enviar solo **errorServer** para obtener lo que necesito.

**Class: EnvioReporte.java**

**Method: generarEnvio()**

```
.....

} catch (HttpStatusCodeException errorServer) {
   logger.error(className + Constantes.PUNTO + methodName + HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_EXCEPTION + errorServer.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Mira este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271417/java-get-the-current-class-name

Answer (score 0):

Comparto el codigo de solucion:

**Class: EnvioReporte.java**

**Method: generarEnvio()**

```
try {
    ..........
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException errorServer) {
    validarRespuestaExcepcion(errorServer, this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}
```

**BaseLogger.java**

```
private static final String IMPLEMENTACION = "Implementacion";
private static final String HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_EXCEPTION = " (HttpServerErrorException): ";

protected HttpHeaders validarRespuestaExcepcion(HttpStatusCodeException errorServer, String pathClassName) {
    HttpHeaders headersResponse = null;
    String className = getClassName(pathClassName);
    String methodName = getMethodName(errorServer.getStackTrace(), pathClassName);
    // Otros errores
    logger.error(className + Constantes.PUNTO + methodName + HTTP_SERVER_ERROR_EXCEPTION + errorServer.getResponseBodyAsString());
    throw new Excepcion(MensajesErrorEnum.GENERAL.getCodigo());
}

private String getClassName(String pathClassName) {
    String className = pathClassName.substring(pathClassName.lastIndexOf(Constantes.PUNTO) + 1);
    int position = className.indexOf(IMPLEMENTACION);
    if (position >= 0) {
        return className.substring(0, position);
    } else {
        return className;
    }
}

private String getMethodName(StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements, String pathClassName) {
    String methodName = null;
    for (StackTraceElement st : stackTraceElements) {
        if (st.getClassName().equals(pathClassName)) {
            methodName = st.getMethodName();
            break;
        }
    }
    return methodName;
}
```

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta